# How Can I Reload the Page Onclick of Submit Button in Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

Hi all I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How can I `Reload` the `Page` `onclick`of `Submit button`. if any one knows the solution please help to us.

I have used codes to `reload the page` as given below:-

**In Controller i have used:-**

```
sryarnpayment.$save(function(response) {
  $location.path('sryarnpayments/' + response._id, {}, { reload: true });

     $scope.name = '';
      }, function(errorResponse) {
        $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
     });
   };
```

**In HTML :-**

```
<div class="controls">

      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">

  </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Just Add it on  onClick Or Sumitform  In button**

```
onclick="window.location.reload()"
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable answer, like this :- <input type="submit" onClick="window.location.reload()"  class="btn btn-default"> right?..

Comment: Hey the above given code is not working in my localhost , so can you please provide some other solution?

Comment: this is correct there is no other code that's it ,I think in your js something is wrong.

Comment: again try it i modified

Answer (score 1):

To redirect page on click or on submit use

```
 app.controller('controller', function ($scope, $http, $window) {

$scope.method = function () {

    //Form Submission
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
        })
          .success(function (response) {
            if (response.status == true)
            {
                $window.location.href = base_url;
            }

        });
     };

    // For onClick:
      $scope.method = function() {
       $window.location.href = base_url;
     }
 });
```

add dependency $window in your controller.

This might help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer can you please tell how can I use your code in my controller , can you please provide the example as well to know the solution, thanks

Comment: app.controller('controller', function ($scope, $http, $window, $location) {
    
    $scope.method = function () {

        $scope.loading = true;
            $http({
                method: 'POST',
            })
              .success(function (response) {
                if (response.status == true)
                {
                   
                    $window.location.href = base_url + 'contact';
                }
                
            });
    };
});

Answer (score 1):

Change `$location.path('sryarnpayments/' + response._id, {}, { reload: true });`

to

ui-router :

`$state.go('STATE_NAME', { id: response._id});`

ng-route :

`$location.path('/sryarnpayments/' + response._id);`

Assuming you have defined route(example below) this should work

Example - Route Definition

ui-router :

```
$stateProvider
.state('STATE_NAME', {
  url: "/sryarnpayments/:id",
  templateUrl: "partials/myPage.html",
  controller: newController
})
```

ng-route :

```
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/sryarnpayments/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'path/myPage.html',
        controller: newController
    });
}]);
```

The parameter can then be accessed in newController as follows:

ui-router :

```
var id = $stateParams.id;
```

ng-route :

```
var id = $routeParams.id;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, this code :- var id = $routeParams.id;  need to add in controller right?.....then what about html part?

Comment: @R.ManiSelvam - you are trying to show the submitted data on the same page after it is saved, right...? so, `id` will give you the saved id and you can use that to fetch your data and then bind that data to your model

Comment: thanks for your comment, your changes and your code is not working in our localhost, it's showing error like - $routeParams is not defined
    at new <anonymous> ..so please give us another solution ...

Comment: did you inject `$routeParams` to your controller `angular.module('app').controller('newController',function ($routeParams) {`

Comment: No I have inject $stateParams in my controller, this is my controller :- .controller('SryarndebitnotesController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location','$filter','Authentication','Buyerinformations','Sryarnpayments','Sryarndebitnotes',
 function($scope, $stateParams, $location, $filter, Authentication, Buyerinformations, Sryarnpayments, Sryarndebitnotes) {